# C# | Invalid expression term '[' (Array.IndexOf()

Tags: c#, массивы, символы

уважаемые знатоки! Прошу не бить, я новичок.
Мне нужно проверить, есть ли в введённом сочетании букв символы и буквы из массивов, я нашёл, что это вроде как можно сделать через Array.IndexOf(). В попытках понять, как вставить в метод целый массив, я столкнулся с тем, что VS2019 выдаёт ошибку на [ в начале массива(Выделил жирным в коде). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему, или же правильный метод для указанной задачи, если я выбрал не тот. (Дальше в коде идёт несколько операторов if, но там вcё правильно)

```
public class Program
    {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        
            {
         
            Console.WriteLine("Enter password:");
            string pass = Console.ReadLine();
            
            string [] letters = { "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M" };
            string [] symbols = {"!", "@", "'", "#", "№", "$", ";", "%", "^", ":", "&", "?", "*", "(", ")", "/", "|", "+", "=", "-"};
            
            int caps = Array.IndexOf(letters, [ "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M" ]);
            int sym = Array.IndexOf(symbols, [ "!", "@", "'", "#", "№", "$", ";", "%", "^", ":", "&", "?", "*", "(", ")", "/", "|", "+", "=", "-"]);
```

Comment: А что вы хотите проверить? Проверить, что строка `pass` не содержит в себе символы из массивов `letters` и `symbols`? или наоборот, проверить, что `pass` состоит исключительно из `letters` и `symbols`?

Comment: да, что не содержит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в c# нет литерала массива.

Поэтому просто написать `[...]` нельзя.

Нужно **создать объект**, для чего используется оператор `new`, например:

```
int caps = Array.IndexOf(letters, new [] { "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M" });
```

Кроме того, вторым параметром должен идти элемент, индекс которого нужно найти, однако в коде выше передается массив.

То есть должно было быть так:

```
int caps = Array.IndexOf(letters, "W");
```

либо так:

```
int caps = Array.IndexOf(new [] { "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M" }, "W");
```

Comment: Почему символы здесь пишутся как строки? Быть может стоило указать автору на этот нюанс?

Comment: @aepot, а почему тут должны писаться символы, а не строки?

Comment: Потому что я не вижу причин для использования массива из строк, которые содержат по одному символу. Выглядит так же странно как массив массивов из одного числа.